# Polymorphism with shared_ptr of base class with 3 level inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I have a base class

```
class Base {
  public:
     virtual void func() = 0;
}
```

I have a concrete derived class

```
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
     void func() {func2();}
     void func2() {};
}
```

Lastly, I have a derived class

```
class DerivedDerived : public Derived {
      // inherits func() from Derived
      void func2() {} //Overrides func2() from Derived
}
void g(shared_ptr<Base> s) {
     s->func();
}
```

Now, my problem is this: I have a function g() that takes a shared_ptr<Base> and calls func() without any typecast because it is unaware of any subclasses.
Now, if I do:

```
shared_ptr<Base> s1 = make_shared<Derived>();
shared_ptr<Base> s2 = make_shared<DerivedDerived>();
g(s1); //func() of Derived Class called
g(s2); //func2() of Derived Class called inside, func2() of DerivedDerived Class needed to be called inside.
```

I want the func() to call func2() of the correct class, i..

Comment: And what *is* the problem? Is the correct function not called? Do you get build errors? Crashes? Unexpected results? Please elaborate. You *have* tried it? Perhaps you even have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us?

Comment: Make `Derived::func2()` `virtual` too.

Comment: *"void func2() {} //Overrides func2() from Derived"*. No, you only **hide** it as func2 is not `virtual`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK since you've changed the code - I'm updating the result, as Jarod42 has mentioned - you are hiding func2 instead of overriding it. I'm also adding override keyword as per AlexanderS suggestion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
void func() override {func2();}
virtual void func2() {std::cout << "func2: Derived\n";};
}
;

class DerivedDerived : public Derived {
public:
     void  func2() override {std::cout << "func2: DerivedDerived\n";} //Overrides func() from Derived
};
void g(std::shared_ptr<Base> s) {
    s->func();
}

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> s1 = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    std::shared_ptr<Base> s2 = std::make_shared<DerivedDerived>();
    g(s1); //func() of Derived Class called
    g(s2); //func() of Derived Class called, func() of DerivedDerived Class needed to
    return 0;
}

/***************
Output:
$ ./test
func2: Derived
func2: DerivedDerived
***************/

/* Compiler error when override is used and func2 is not marked virtual
   src/test.cpp:19:16: error: ‘void DerivedDerived::func2()’ marked ‘override’, but does not override
      void  func2() override {std::cout << "func2: DerivedDerived\n";} //Overrides func() from Derived
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to this topic, since C++11 there is the [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword, wich prevents these kind of errors. When you use it, it throws an compiler error if you are not overriding the method you used the keyword on.

```
class DerivedDerived : public Derived {
      void func2() {} override; // would throw an error in your case
}
```